# Join two tables on two columns

Tags: sql, inner-join

I am trying to join an sql table on to another one if two of the rows are the same in both tables.

This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT a.name1, a.name2, b.score
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
ON a.name1=b.name1
AND a.name2=b.name2
```

This does not appear to work for me. Obviously I am an sql noob. Any help appreciated.

Sample data:

```
Table A
123456789_111_000001,123456789_111_000002

Table B
123456789_111_000001,123456789_111_000002,1.023658
```

Edit: Okay, it's working now. I must have had some syntax error or something the first time. It took 10 minutes to run and didn't return anything. Should I delete the question?

Comment: will [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396817/join-two-tables-based-on-two-columns) help ?

Comment: Your query should work, can you provide the data in table a and b?

Comment: Please provide sample data.

Comment: there are no any syntax errors and it also do what you want! it might be caused by other problems, please provide detailed error information.

Comment: Share the sample data along with the expected result.. In principle there is no issue in ur stament. It shld give the expected result..

Comment: @Mitchell what you want? do you want return rows only if the condition matched for more than one rows?